# Using Highcharts with mysql for Page Visits

Tags: php, mysql, sql, highcharts

I am trying to use Highcharts to display user visits per property, however I am unsure how to set up the SQL query to properly display this. It would be a lot easier if our database simply listed page visits during specific periods of time, but it's stored per-user, per-property, per visit, as you can see here:

[image: Data]

I know that I have to query the sum visits per property and sort it by month, but exactly the best way to do this is beyond me. This what I've got so far:

```
    <?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('demeure', $con);

//$date_start = $_POST['date_start'];
//$date_end = $_POST['date_end'];
$date_start = '2012-07-01 00:00:00';
$date_end = '2012-08-01 00:00:00';

$result = mysql_query("
  SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS count,
    created_at
  FROM
    user_property_visits
  WHERE
    created_at BETWEEN '$date_start' AND '$date_end'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['count'] . "\t" . $row['created_at']. "\n";
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

This results with a blank page. I'm not sure how close I am to getting what I need, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with the following:

```
    <?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$database = "demeure_new";

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$database;host=$host";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$query = "SELECT DAY(created_at) AS day, MONTH(created_at) AS month, YEAR(created_at) AS year, count(user_id) AS count FROM user_property_views GROUP BY day";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->closeCursor();

$newArray = array();
foreach($result as $r)
  $newArray[$r["year"]][$r["month"]][$r["day"]] = $r["count"];

//print_r($newArray);

json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

echo json_encode($newArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want this, but you can filter the period in the `WHERE` clause. Check if it could help:

```php
<?php

// Show all PHP errors.
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Connect with MySQL
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'your_user', 'your_password');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('demeure', $con);

// Obtain date range from $_POST or
// manually edit this.

//$date_start = $_POST['date_start'];
//$date_end = $_POST['date_end'];
$date_start = '2012-07-20 20:30:00';
$date_end = '2012-07-20 20:37:00';

// Query with GROUP BY
$result = mysql_query("
  SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS `count`,
    created_at
  FROM
    user_property_visits
  WHERE
    created_at BETWEEN '$date_start' AND '$date_end'
  GROUP BY
    created_at");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo 'Count: ' . $row['count'] . '<br/>' . 'Group by date: ' . $row['created_at'] . '<br/>';
}

// With the schema used in SQL Fiddle, this code will reproduce
//
// A PHP Error was encountered
// Severity: 8192
// Message: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
// will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead
//
// Filename: views/home.php
//
// Line Number: 7
//
// Count: 4
// Group by date: 2012-07-20 20:36:28

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Using this, you can use a datepicker, for example, to select the date range and obtain this values via POST (ajax).

[**Check this SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/531b4/16)

Comment: After replacing the query with this it comes up with a blank page; do I need to change the $echo in order to display this properly?

Comment: I've put just the query. I'll edit with entire code like you've posted.

Comment: I saw your edit a couple of minutes ago and tried to use it, but unfortunately it's giving me the same result of a blank page. I tried copy-and-pasting what you wrote and just replaced the database info but no luck

Comment: Check if your development environment is showing errors. Try to put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the start of the code to show possible errors. I'm trying this code in SQL Fiddle, wait some minutes than I will share with you.

Comment: In Chrome there's a quick flash of a 500 error when I refresh but it disappears after the page loads. I'll be trying some other troubleshooting methods and post here after

Comment: It checks out in SQL Fiddle, so I'm not sure at this point where the 500 server error could be or why the function isn't working

Comment: Check again the code I've edit please. I've corrected some errors and tried locally in my development environment with the schema of updated SQL Fiddle: **http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/531b4/16**